# Hypothetical design: Dynamic binding of element, event and function which is in an array or Set using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

Function Object is

```
var obj = {
    func1: function () {
        console.log('func1');
    },
    func2: function () {
        console.log('func2');
    }
}
```

simplified html is

```
    <input type="button" id="btnOne" value="One"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="Two"/>
```

I would like to have an array of arrays in Javascript

```
var arrObj = [["btnOne", "click", obj.func1], ["btnTwo", "click", obj.func2] ];
```

where dynamic bindings can be done using

```
arrObj.forEach(function(elm){
let x = document.getElementbyId(elm[0]);
   if (x !== "undefined"){
      x.addEventListener(elm[1], elm[2]);
   }
}
```

Somehow this did not work for me.

Is this doable ?

Comment: If I were you, I'd use an object to encapsulate the parts, rather than array indexes. Something like `{ id: "btnOne", eventName: "click", eventListener: obj.func1 }`. Then programmers coming back to the code later don't have to keep toggling between the array code and the `forEach` code to make sure they've put the right things at the right index.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you add the closing brace (`)`)  to your `.forEach` and fix the typo in `.getElementById`:

```js
var obj = {
    func1: function () {
        console.log('func1');
    },
    func2: function () {
        console.log('func2');
    }
}

var arrObj = [["btnOne", "click", obj.func1], ["btnTwo", "click", obj.func2] ];

arrObj.forEach(function(elm) {
let x = document.getElementById(elm[0]); // <--- here
   if (x !== "undefined"){
      x.addEventListener(elm[1], elm[2]);
   }
}); // <--- here
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnOne" value="One"/>
<input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="Two"/>
```